# How is multitasking implemented at the elementary level?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, multitasking

How is the multitasking implemented at the basic level ? To clarify my question, lets say we are given a C runtime to make an application which implements multitasking, which can run only one task at a time on a single core processor, say, by calling `main()` function of this "mutlitasking" application. 
How do standard OS kernels implement this ? How does this change with multicore processors

Answer (score 1):

OS sets an interrupt timer, and lets the program run. Once the timer expires, control flow jumps to code of the OS for context switch.

On the context switch OS saves registers and supporting data of the current process and replaces it in CPU with data of the next process in queue. Then it sets another interrupt timer and let the next program run from where it was interrupted.

Also a system call from the current process gives control to the OS to decide if it is time for a context switch (eq. process is waiting for an IO operation)

The mechanics is transparent for programs.

Run. Switch. Repeat. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've not done much work with multi-core processors, so I will refrain from attempting to answer that part of the query.  However, with uniprocessors, two strategies come to mind when it comes to multi-tasking.

1. If I remember correctly, the x86 supports hardware task switching.  (I've had minimal experience with this type of multi-tasking.)  From what I recall, when the processor detects the conditions for a task switch, it automatically saves all the registers of the outgoing task into its Task State Segment (x86), and loads all the registers from the incoming task's Task State Segment.  There are various caveats and limitations with this approach such as the 'busy bit' being set and only being able to switched back to a 'busy task' under special conditions.  Personally, I do not find this method to be particularly useful to me.
2. The more common solution that I have seen is task switching by software.  This, can be broken down into cooperative task switching and pre-emptive task switching.  If you are coding up a cooperative task switching strategy, a task switch only occurs when the task voluntarily gives up the processor.  In this strategy, you only need to save and load the non-volatile registers.  If a pre-emptive strategy is chosen, then a task switch can occur either voluntarily, or non-voluntarily.  In this case, all the registers must be saved and loaded.  When coding either scenario, you have to pay extra care that you do not corrupt your register contents and that you set up your stack correctly so that when you return from task-switching code you are at the right place on the stack of the incoming task.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That certainly helps, thank you, but the topic definitely deserves further description.